# How to copy formula from a selected range and copy it to the next empty row with macros

Tags: vba, excel

I will be adding data into my workbook everyday and I will normally use a set of formulas to calculate rate of failures and success for me. I already have the code for compiling the data but what I lack now is how to copy the set of formulas for the next empty cell so that it can help me calculate the rates. My set of formula is added from "P22" to "AB22", and I need to copy those formulas to next empty row. This is the macros i have now, if kind enough do check and see if there are places for improvement as i'm still new to vba. Thank you very much.

```
Sub trial()

Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wb3 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim fn As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))
Dim Ret

    Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("Lkl Files (*.lkl), *.lkl")

    If Ret <> False Then
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & Ret, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "SPC_PLTB_450B_12092107_25°C_CW"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 65001
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileDecimalSeparator = ","
        .TextFileThousandsSeparator = "."
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

        End With
    End If


    Sheets(2).Activate

    'this is for the date (loop)

    Dim FirstCell As String
        Dim i As Integer
            FirstCell = "C19"
            Range(FirstCell).Select
            Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            Exit Do
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
            Loop
            ActiveCell = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    ws.Activate
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Range("$A$9:$P$417").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
        "1"
    Range("F31:F401").Select
    Selection.Copy



    Sheets(2).Activate


    'this is for the raw data

            FirstCell = "D19"
            Range(FirstCell).Select
            Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            Exit Do
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
            Loop


    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True

   Sheets(3).Activate
    FirstCell = "C19"
            Range(FirstCell).Select
            Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            Exit Do
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
            Loop
            ActiveCell = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    ws.Activate

    Range("D31:D401").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy


    Sheets(3).Activate
            FirstCell = "D19"
            Range(FirstCell).Select
            Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            Exit Do
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
            Loop


    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True

        Sheets(4).Activate
    FirstCell = "C19"
            Range(FirstCell).Select
            Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            Exit Do
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
            Loop
            ActiveCell = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    ws.Activate

    Range("G31:G401").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy



    Sheets(4).Activate
    FirstCell = "D19"
            Range(FirstCell).Select
            Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            Exit Do
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
            Loop


    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True


End Sub
```

Example of my worksheet

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's tricky to give an ideal solution without knowing more about your existing Excel file, but I made some assumptions based on what you posted and put together an Excel file with a couple possible solutions for you.

Since we can't attach files to posts here I uploaded it to free file host [FileTown](https://file.town); you can download the [macro-disabled] XLSX [file here](https://file.town/download/4sznrtaakurz1hfxphmpg3lz3).

Follow the steps starting on sheet '**Example1**' for an example of what I meant about creating formulas *now* for the data you will add *later*, as well as how to make charts auto-update by making your data into an Excel 'table', and how to create a Data Connection to your source data file so you don't need to re-import it any time the data changes, all **without macros**.

Not to deter you from learning about VBA & macro's but Excel has some very powerful built-in data management features which, in this case, might be a better approach than a custom one.

On the other hand, I first starting learning VBA (in the 90's with Excel v.5) by recording macros while doing simple repetitive tasks, and then experimenting with the generated VBA by "changing this line or deleting that one" and seeing what happened; about half of the code Excel auto-generates in a recorded macro is probably extraneous.  (Just make a backup copy of your files before messing with them, and check [MSDN/VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/vba-language-reference) or Google for anything you're curious about, and there's nothing to lose...  I'm a big fan of Excel because, between VBA and its' built-in functions, its' capabilities are endless!)

Comment: Thank you so much @ashleedawg !! Wasn't expecting something so detailed but thanks a lot haha.. Although I was thinking of doing it with Macros but I think manually dragging it down for 100 rows should be fine I guess..

Comment: You're welcome.  Don't worry, you'll have *plenty* more opportunities to get super-complicated with MS Office!

Answer (score 0):

Not to sway you from learning VBA, but I think you can get away without it in this case.

You could make a small change to the formulas in "P22" to "AB22" so that they stay blank if there is no data in "D to N".

Using your example, copy cell P22 and paste into cell P23.  Next, put an "if" statement around your formula, like:

```
=IF ( D23 = "" , "" , {your existing formula here} )
```

...and "fill" that formula to the right, and down a few dozen rows.  Cells "P to AB" will be blank until you enter data on the left side of your worksheet.  It's tough to explain but if this doesn't make sense I can send you a sample worksheet. I

Comment: Will appreciate it if I can have a sample worksheet to guide me through it.. From your example, does it make me hard code the macros ? Because for my case, hard coding is not really preferable as I will be putting more and more data into it.. So, searching for the next empty row would be better.. Or i just am too new to understand what you code there really sorry if i mistaken you..